# CakePHP 3 : multi level association

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-3.2

I have 3 tables, `categories`, `products` and `seller_products` and their associations are like
**CategoriesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Products', [
   'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
]);
```

**ProductsTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('SellerProducts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Categories', [
    'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**SellerProductsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Now, In the `view` of `categories` (`site.com/categories/view/2`), I have to select all products data from `products` and `sellerProducts` where products belongs to category id and also exists in sellerProducts.
ie.,

```
products.category_id = $id AND sellerProducts.product_id = Products.id
```

Is there any easy way in CakePHP 3 to get the result ?

> Edit 2

This is what I'm trying. In `view()` action of `CategoriesController.php`

```
$this->loadModel('Products');
        $sellerProducts = $this->Products->find('all', [
          'conditions' => [
            'category_id' => $id
          ],
          'joins' => [
              'table' => 'SellerProducts',
              'alias' => 'SellerProducts',
              'type' => 'INNER',
              'conditions' => [
                'SellerProducts.product_id' => 'Products.id',
                'stock >' => 0
              ]
            ]
        ]);
        debug($sellerProducts);
        foreach($sellerProducts as $a) {
          debug($a);
        }
```

on `debug` it gives only the data from `Products` table but not from `SellerProducts`

Comment: Seems a very simple task, what didi you try so far?

Comment: @arilia see `edit 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of join you can simply contain SellerProducts

```
$this->Products->find()
    ->where(['category_id' => $id])
    ->contain(['SellerProducts' => function($q) {
        return $q->where(['stock >' => 0])
    }]);
```

if you want to query the data from sellerproducts you can do

```
 $this->Products->SellerProducts->find()
    ->where([
         'Products.category_id' => $id
         'SellerProducts.stock >' => 0])
    ->contain(['Products', 'Products.Categories']);
```

Comment: this gives result in `2D` array in which 1st array contain `products` and 2nd array contains all `sellerProducts` associated with that product. I want all data in single array because I have to run many other functions later on the data retrieved like to find `min('selling_price')` and `max('selling_price')` which are in `sellerProducts`. and also to get only one seller with each product with minimum `selling_price`, etc. I think it will be easy to run these functions later on result of join.